# Rails 4.2.6 app deployed using puma not loading assets and images.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

Earlier I have deployed the same source code using passenger and unicorn with capistrano and nginx. There it was working fine. But now I am trying to do the same using Puma server. The assets are not loading at all.

**environment/production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true


  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true


  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  config.assets.compile = true

  config.assets.digest = true



  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: ENV["SMTP_HOST"] }
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = ENV["SMTP_HOST"]
  # config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    #Enter the smtp provider here ex: smtp.mandrillapp.com
    address: ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"],
    port: ENV['SMTP_PORT'].to_i,
    #Enter the smtp domain here ex: xxx.com
    domain: ENV["SMTP_DOMAIN"],
    #Enter the user name for smtp provider here
    user_name: ENV["SMTP_USERNAME"],
    #Enter the password for smtp provider here
    password: ENV["SMTP_PASSWORD"],
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

**capfile**

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require "capistrano/scm/hg"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/svn"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

require 'capistrano/rails'
#require 'capistrano/passenger'

# If you are using rvm add these lines:
require 'capistrano/rvm'
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.2.4'

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
require "capistrano/rvm"
# require "capistrano/rbenv"
# require "capistrano/chruby"
require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/rails/assets"
require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
# require "capistrano/passenger"
require 'capistrano/puma'

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your `Nginx config file` whether it is allowing assets(images, fonts etc.) for your application or not.

```
location ^~ /(assets|fonts|swfs|images)/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
```

Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you already didn't, adding rails_12factor gem is solving this kind of similar issue for me

hope it helps.

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

-- UPDATE --

Also there are duplicate requires in your capfile. Below is a clean version for Capfile. You need to move the rvm setting to deploy.rb. You don't need to use bundler, assets and migration if you are including capistrano/rails

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require "capistrano/scm/hg"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/svn"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/puma'
# require "capistrano/rvm"
# require "capistrano/rbenv"
# require "capistrano/chruby"
# require "capistrano/bundler"
# require "capistrano/rails/assets"
# require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
# require "capistrano/passenger"

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

Comment: I added it to the gem file. Deployed it. Restarted the server. But still the assets are not loading

Comment: Do the compiled assets exists with different names or is it not even being compiled? You should be able to see it in capistrano outputs during deploy

Answer (score 0):

You should run the precompilation command before deploying your files, and that increases the performance.

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precomile
```

After that, just commit the changes and deploy your files.

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets